# Why does Kafka Connect Sftp source directory need to be writeable?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

using the connector: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-sftp/source-connector/index.html

When I config the connector and check the status I get the bellow exception...

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Directory for 'input.path' '/FOO' it not writable.\n\tat io.confluent.connect.sftp.source.SftpDirectoryPermission.directoryWritable
```

This makes no sense from a source stand point especially if you are connecting to a 3rd party source you do NOT control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write permissions because the Connector will **move** the files that it read to the configurable `finished.path`. This movement into `finished.path` is explained in the [link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-sftp/source-connector/index.html#sftp-source-connector-for-cp) you have provided:

> Once a file has been read, it is placed into the configured finished.path directory.

The documentation on the configuration `input.path` states that you need write access to it:

> `input.path` - The directory where Kafka Connect reads files that are processed. This directory must exist and be writable by the user running Connect.

Comment: I know. But makes it unusable as a connector if you want to use it with SFTP that you do not control or a read only SFTP. The state should be saved on separate folder. Oh well...